# Exporting CSV Files from one region to S3 bucket in a different region

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, region

I am attempting to export a CSV file for AWS Compute Optimizer from one region, to a bucket in a different region.

Is this something that is possible to do, pushing data directly from one region to a bucket in another?

Cross-replication involves pushing data to a bucket in one region, then replicating to a bucket in another, which involves an extra step I would like to avoid and charges if objects are not deleted.

Thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Are you wanting to save directly to the "bucket in a different region", or are you wanting to save to a "bucket in the same region" and then copy that object to the other bucket? Are you wanting to do the copy yourself, or are you wanting it to happen automatically? The region of a bucket should not impact how you use the bucket. What have you tried so far? Can you show us some code? Is it working? Please Edit your question to provide more details, rather than answering via a comment.